# Error with pyrebase installation in python

Tags: python

I have tried installing pyrebase in python django using python version 3.10 but it returns this error.
"Failed to build pycryptodome
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pycryptodome, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects"
Any idea about that?

I was trying to integrate firebase in django using pyrebase but it couldnt continue successsfully

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: @ewokx is correct a full traceback error would be great but you can also just try and run ```pip install pycryptodome --verbose``` That will give us a more detailed output of whats going wrong when trying to build that package.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.